# split a list into sublists and pass them one by one into an algorithm

Tags: java, list, apache-spark, arraylist, collections

I have a list of type string that contains multiple items in the form

```
[Cid:0001,Jid:439,java,unit testing]
[Cid:0001,Jid:439,java,jsp,xml,javascript,servlet,html]
[Cid:0001,Jid:245,ui development,jquery,javascript,html,ajax]
[Cid:0002,Jid:312,team,goals,territory]
```

and so on

Since there are a lot of items, i need to group the items based on Cid and Jid. Example, The first two lines above should be one group as it has the same Cid and Jid.

I need to pass each of the groups one by one at a time into an algorithm that takes a JavaRDD format as input.Each list is parallelized using the parallelize function in spark.

```
List<List<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Resume r : resumes) {
  List<String> subList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String temp : hashSet) {
    if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase(r.getJid() + r.getCid())) { 
      subList.add(r.toString());
      mainList.add(subList);
```

Comment: so you want to merge the data if they have the same Cid and Jid ?

Comment: merge them and keep them as a list to be passed to the algorithm(one list at a time).

Comment: can you share the resume class for better options

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code snippet :

```
        Resume r1 = new Resume();
        r1.setJid("123");
        r1.setCid("2900");
        r1.setRes("java,unit testing");

        Resume r2 = new Resume();
        r2.setJid("1232");
        r2.setCid("900");
        r2.setRes("java,jsp,xml,javascript,servlet,html");

        Resume r3 = new Resume();
        r3.setJid("123");
        r3.setCid("2900");
        r3.setRes("ui development,jquery,javascript,html,ajax");

        List<Resume> resumes = new ArrayList<Resume>();
        resumes.add(r1);
        resumes.add(r2);
        resumes.add(r3);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Resume r : resumes) {
            StringBuilder subList = new StringBuilder();
            subList.append("\""+r.toString()+"\"");
            if (map.containsKey("JID:" + r.getJid()+"+" + "CID:" + r.getCid())) {
                subList.append(","+map.get("JID:" + r.getJid()+"+" + "CID:" + r.getCid()));
            }
            map.put("JID:" + r.getJid()+"+" + "CID:" + r.getCid(),subList.toString());

        }

        for(String key:map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("{"+key+map.get(key)+"}");
        }
```

Output :

```
{JID:123+CID:2900"ui development,jquery,javascript,html,ajax","java,unit testing"}
{JID:1232+CID:900"java,jsp,xml,javascript,servlet,html"}
```

I have used  `"JID"+r.getJid()+"CID"+r.getCid()` to consider the case where

JId : 212 and Cid: 456

JId : 2124 and Cid : 56

As they are not supposed to be grouped together.
Adding Key as `r.getJid() + r.getCid()` will not help you to consider this case

Comment: The code above didn't work. It printed all the items but not sorted. My earlier code worked fine and groups all jid and cid correctly but it is not split into different  lists, instead all of it passes as a single list into the algorithm. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AshwinThomas Hope this works. You just have to look at map.values()

Comment: The Jid+Cid combination is repeating for each line which is not required. I expect something like this:  {Jid:54+Cid:12:"java,unit testing","java,jsp","jsp,html,java"}
where Jid:54+Cid:12 is the key and the other part of skills is the value.
Also this is for a group of values having Jid:54 and Cid:12.

Comment: @AshwinThomas Hope this matches your output :)